# Xamarin ListView is empty or doesn't get filled

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a ContentPage with a ListView like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewMain">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="Employee Name" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                <Image Source="VoteUp.png" VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Image Source="VoteDown.png" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding image}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                                <Image Source="Favorite.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                <Image Source="Send.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                <Image Source="Save.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the page constructor:

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListViewMain.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomViewCell));
}
```

And here is the CustomViewCell:

```
public class CustomViewCell: ViewCell
{
    public CustomViewCell()
    {
        //instantiate each of our views
        var image = new Image();
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "Example_Image.jpg");
    }
}
```

I added all the icon images to the drawable folder in the android path, but when I launch the app, the whole page is blank and there is no picture at all. What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

Now I have added a ListSource to the ListView, but my result is very small:
[image]

How can I make the row WAY bigger?

Comment: Place your images in drawable-hdpi folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `CustomViewCell` you create `image` but never assign it to the view hierarchy.  You are also not setting the binding path correctly - you need to specify the name of a public property on your model

```
public CustomViewCell()
{
    //instantiate each of our views
    var image = new Image();
    image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "name_of_some_property");
    this.View = image;
}
```

Comment: Still a blank list!?

Comment: where are you assigning your ItemsSource?

Comment: This is the only code I use for the ListView.... Where should I put that?

Comment: And why are you assigning DataTemplate in XAML and Code?  Do one or the other, not both

Comment: Where you are getting your data from?  Typically you do it in the page constructor or OnAppearing

Comment: I want to do a https web request to get the picture and the "Employee Name", but I wanted to test the look first, so I added an example image to the drawable folder and now I want to set the picture of the drawable folder to the ListView image as an example

Comment: a ListView won't display anything if it doesn't have any data.  You need to create at least one dummy element and add it to a List then assign it to the ItemsSource

Comment: I have added a part to my question below. I now have an Itemsource assigned to the list

Answer (score 0):

As jason said, I didn't see where is your data source, CustomViewCell is the datetemplate, so you assign image value for image control, it still don't display, because ListView control is the collection control, you should assign one collection for it.

Doing one sample, you can take a look:

```
 public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
{
   public CustomViewCell()
    {
        //instantiate each of our views

        var image = new Image() { WidthRequest = 30, HeightRequest = 30 };

        var verticaLayout = new StackLayout();


        //set bindings          
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, new Binding("Image"));
        verticaLayout.Children.Add(image);

        // add to parent view

        View = verticaLayout;

        //var image = new Image() { WidthRequest=30,HeightRequest=30};
        //image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "check.png");
        //this.View = image;
    }


}

public class VeggieViewModel
{ 
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public partial class Page13 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<VeggieViewModel> veggies { get; set; }
    public Page13 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        veggies = new ObservableCollection<VeggieViewModel>();
        ListViewMain.RowHeight = 60;

        ListViewMain.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomViewCell));
        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Image = "check.png" });

        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel {  Image = "facebook.png" });

        veggies.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Image = "icaon.png" });
        ListViewMain.ItemsSource = veggies;
    }
}
```